# Change Button to Image Navigation Slider Javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I found a tutorial about create a simple slideshow with JavaScript. So i try it and it was success. But the navigation is in button type for Play/Stop.

I want to change it to an image navigation called play and another image called stop. When i click on play image, image stop will appear and play image will be hidden. And when i click stop image, play image will appear and stop image will stop.

Here is my JavaScript:

```
var interval = 2000; // You can change this value to your desired speed. The value is in milliseconds, so if you want to advance a slide every 5 seconds, set this to 5000.
    var switching = setInterval("toggleSlide(true)", interval);

    window.paused = false;

    function toggleInterval() {
        var button = document.getElementById("pauseButton");
        if(!window.paused) {
            clearInterval(switching);
            button.value = "Resume";
        } else {
            switching = setInterval("toggleSlide(true)", interval);
            button.value = "Pause";
        }
        window.paused = !(window.paused);
    }
```

And here is my HTML (First):

```
<div align="right">
    <input id="pauseButton" onclick="toggleInterval()" type="button" value="Pause" />
</div>
```

And this is my HTML now:

```
<div align="right">
    <img src="../asset/images/play.png" title="Play" id="pauseButton" onclick="toggleInterval()" />
    <img src="../asset/images/stop.png" style="cursor:pointer; display:none;" title="Stop" onclick="toggleinterval(true)" />
</div>
```

Thanks for the answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of having `img` element in your `button`, you can work with `classes` and `background-image` css. It's easier to manage afterwards, you simply set the class you need and the image will change according to this. Something like this allows you to switch images easily:

```js
window.paused = true;

// You can keep the same logic as with your button
// but instead of changing value, you change the class
// And in your css you assign different images to different classes


function toggleInterval() {
  var button = document.getElementById("pauseButton");
  if (!window.paused) {
    
    button.className = 'resume';
  } else {

    button.className = 'pause';
  }
  window.paused = !(window.paused);
}
```

```css
#pauseButton {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  background-size: contain;
}
#pauseButton.pause {
  background-image: url('https://encrypted-tbn0.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcTqDrugj4g4aPOBxEXi7zv1zH_c1OXaaWbOg8HRkQuVDhb8LVn46PP8wTo')
}
#pauseButton.resume {
  background-image: url('https://images-eu.ssl-images-amazon.com/images/G/02/uk-electronics/product_content/Nikon/ECS-NK1308141-B00ECGX8FM-2L-1024w683q85s10-BKEH_London_Paris__0316.jpg')
}
```

```html
<div>
  <div id="pauseButton" class="resume" onclick="toggleInterval()"></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

A simple trick

Set the pause tag to display: block; and put it to the back

```
<div align="right">
    <img src="../asset/images/play.png" style="position: relative; z-index: 1;" title="Play" id="pauseButton" onclick="toggleInterval()" />
    <img src="../asset/images/stop.png" style="position: absolute; z-index: 0;" title="Stop" onclick="toggleinterval(true)" />
</div>
```

And remove opacity from Play when you click it.

```
function toggleInterval() {
    var button = document.getElementById("pauseButton");
    if(!window.paused) {
        clearInterval(switching);
        button.value = "Resume";
        //here is the trick
        button.style.opacity = 1;
    } else {
        switching = setInterval("toggleSlide(true)", interval);
        button.value = "Pause";
        //here is the trick
        button.style.opacity = 0;
    }
    window.paused = !(window.paused);
}
```